# Inserting CrossReference to word via Delphi XE5

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, word-2010

Bonjour, Hello,

I'm making this delphi application that I use to create word documents. I'm done with basic word operations (create/save, text, tables..etc).

What I need to do is to insert Page Numbers of headings as Cross Reference in the text. Something like :

"... and the process works as explained on page 23..."

where page number is a hyperlink to a heading. When I recorded a Macros in word it looks like:

```
    Selection.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:="Heading", _
    ReferenceKind:=wdPageNumber, ReferenceItem:="49", InsertAsHyperlink:=True _
    , IncludePosition:=False, SeparateNumbers:=False, SeparatorString:=" "
```

What would be the equivalent in Delphi please?

Thanks in advance!
Arjun.

Comment: Are you using early or late binding?

Comment: @SilentD,
I think I'm using 'LateBinding'.  Well my code looks similar to latebinding. As far as I understand here... 
[Link](http://delphi.about.com/od/kbcontrolole/ss/word_automation_3.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when you're using Late Binding you still need to provide all of the parameters in the same order as the original declaration.

```
expression.InsertCrossReference(ReferenceType, ReferenceKind, ReferenceItem,
InsertAsHyperlink, IncludePosition, SeparateNumbers, SeparatorString)
```

If you aren't using a parameter then you can replace it with EmptyParam.

So I think your code will be:

```
Selection.InsertCrossReference('Heading', 7, '49', True, False, False, ' ');
```

(I think that wdPageNumber's value is 7).

Comment: this works perfect!!! Thanks a ton!
I was trying to put in 'wdPageNumber' as a parameter.
Now I just need to find a way to replace 'ReferenceItem' number with the heading text. There should be something that gives a heading's 'ReferenceItem'.

Thanks again :)